# Find matching NSThread for NSRunLoop (needed to fix Socket Rocket)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, websocket, core-foundation

I'm working on a fix for a race condition in [Socket Rocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket).
This bug was reported a long time ago and is still not fixed.

More than a year ago I've written a fix which breaks API (only shared thread can be used) and this code is running successfully on production (no crashes at all when there are lots of users).

Now I want to tweak my fix in such way that it will not break API of `SRWebSocket`.
For that, I need to find matching `NSThread` forgiven `NSRunLoop`. This is one to one relation, but I have problem finding an API which could help me.

---

PS. A fix is quite simple. Every operation made on `NSRunLoop` must be done from a respective thread. There is no `NSRunLoop` or CFRunLoop`API that can be safely used from another thread. So I've added such API to`SRRunLoopThread`:

```
- (void)scheduleBlock: (void(^)())block
{
    [self performSelector: @selector(_runBlock:)
                 onThread: self
               withObject: [block copy]
            waitUntilDone: NO];
}

- (void)_runBlock: (void(^)())block
{
    block();
}
```

and use it in every place where something is done on this `NSRunLoop`.

This fix shows why I need to find matching `NSThread`.

Note [documentations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414476-performselector) states that `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` is thread safe

> You can use this method to deliver messages to other threads in your application.

I have to stress again that [documentation warns clearly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsrunloop) that `NSRunLoop` API is NOT threaded safe:

> **Warning**
>
> The **NSRunLoop** class is generally not considered to be thread-safe and
>   its methods should only be called within the context of the current
>   thread. You should never try to call the methods of a **NSRunLoop**
>   object running in a different thread, as doing so might cause
>   unexpected results.

Since `CFRunLoop` is just the same thing which can by toil free bridged to/from `NSRunLoop`, so it has exactly same weaknesses.
So if documentation doesn't say that API it threads safe, then it is not threaded safe and I can't use it in that context (so proposed answer from @DisableR is obviously invalid).

Comment: Can’t you use `-performBlock:` method of NSRunLoop instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform blocks having a runloop without need of a thread.
Block will be performed asynchronously on a thread that is associated with the run loop.

```
CFRunLoopPerformBlock([myNSRunLoop getCFRunLoop], kCFRunLoopCommonModes, block);
CFRunLoopWakeUp([myNSRunLoop getCFRunLoop]);
```

Here is a discussion about implementation of `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` method of `NSThread` on macOS Tiger where it was not available, the problem that is quite similar to yours:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/112261-cfrunlooptimer-firing-delay.html

**Verifying the thread safety:**

```
import Foundation

var runLoopFromThread: CFRunLoop!
let lock = NSLock()
lock.lock()
let thread = Thread {
    autoreleasepool {
        runLoopFromThread = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
        lock.unlock()
        while true {
            autoreleasepool {
                CFRunLoopRun()
            }
        }
    }
}

thread.start()
lock.lock()
let runLoop = runLoopFromThread
lock.unlock()


let racingLock = NSLock()
for _ in 0..<10000 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let acquired = racingLock.try()
        CFRunLoopPerformBlock(runLoop, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes.rawValue) {
            var i = 0
            i += 1
        }
        CFRunLoopWakeUp(runLoop);
        if acquired {
            racingLock.unlock()
        } else {
            print("Potential situation in which issues with thread safety may arise. No crash / thread sanitizer warnings means thread safety is present.")
        }
    }
}
dispatchMain()
```

Comment: Note this API is not thread safe. Documentation clearly states that all `NSRunLoop` methods are not thread safe. Also this API doesn't wake run loop so application can get stuck. Also I need to support OS X 10.10 and iOS 9.

Comment: Then, CF approach is the way to go. CFRunLoop procedures are thread safe. Documentation also says: "If you want the work performed right away, you must explicitly wake up that thread using the CFRunLoopWakeUp function".

Comment: Again problem here is thread safety of the API! Show me in documentation that this API is thread safe. I've updated question to prove that `NSRunLoop` API can't be used.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html Core Foundation is sufficiently thread-safe that, if you program with care, you should not run into any problems related to competing threads. It is thread-safe in the common cases, such as when you query, retain, release, and pass around immutable objects. Even **central shared objects** that might be queried from more than one thread are reliably thread-safe.

Comment: On the other hand, here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html it's stated that: "The Cocoa NSRunLoop class is not as inherently thread safe as its Core Foundation counterpart. If you are using the NSRunLoop class to modify your run loop, you should do so only from the same thread that owns that run loop. Adding an input source or timer to a run loop belonging to a different thread could cause your code to crash or behave in an unexpected way."

Comment: This statement can be related only to timers/input sources, because they might capture thread context of the thread where they were created. With blocks it can still be fine.

Comment: I am talking now about CFRunLoop, not NSRunLoop. NSRunLoop is not toll-free bridged to CFRunLoop, so those are two different stories, and work with certain CFRunLoop functions is thread safe, as it is stated here: https://reformatcode.com/code/ios/semaphore-with-nsrunloop-not-working-since-upgrade-to-ios10

Comment: Ok I've granted you a bounty, but still I have a doubt you are right. Currently I do not have time to verify it (I've been move to another project).

Comment: Feel free to PM me if you have further questions.

Comment: It is not matter of questions, but verification (testing inspecting source code). Thanks for links anyway.